# JFrame добавить картинку

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

Ребят, как правильно добавить картинку в окно? Когда я добавляю у меня она за экран уходит.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {

private int width = 300;
private int height = 300;

private Image img;

public Window() {
    setSize(width, height);
    setTitle("File Monitor:D");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void loadImage(String src) {
    img = new ImageIcon(src).getImage();
}

public void drawIcon() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае укажите в качестве размеров рисуемого изображения размер окна

```
public void drawIcon() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй JLabel , например так:

```
    ImageIcon icon1 = createIcon("images/settings.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon1);
    panel.add(label).setBounds(10,10,27,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новый метод:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
protected void setImage(String path /* Принимает путь картинки */) {
    File f; // Создаём файл
    f = new File(path); // Устанавливаем путь для файла
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(f); // Считываем картинку
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Что-то неправильно!\n" + ioe.toString(), 
                "Error!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jp.add("Center", jl);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте, пожалуйста, JavaFX вариант:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Window extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Загружаем изображение (указываем путь)
        Image image = new Image("image.png");
        // Загруженное изображение отображаем в контейнере.
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        // Контейнеру прописываем расположение в контейнере верхнего уровня
        imageView.setLayoutX(0);
        imageView.setLayoutY(0);

        // Контейнером верхнего уровня будет Группа. Она же будет корнем сцены приложения.
        Group root = new Group();
        // Добавляем дочерний элемент к корню - наш контейнер отображения картинки.
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);

        // Создаём сцену. (корень, ширина окна, высота окна)
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        // Имя приложения в шапке окна.
        primaryStage.setTitle("Картинка");
        // Назначаем сцену приложению.
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // Отображаем сцену.
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Если использование JFrame принципиально: решение есть здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777893/jframe-background-image (загрузка изображения и установка его как фона окна)